# LSTM for Time Series: lags, timesteps, epochs, batchsize

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, deep-learning, lstm

I was doing the various Machine Learning Mastery tutorials but I got very confused. Some answers (for instance [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264546/difference-between-samples-time-steps-and-features-in-neural-network) and many others) helped me but I still am confused.

**Difference between batch_size, timesteps, lags and what are the correct input dimensions?**

I will provide you with an example.
I have a time series

`timeSeries = np.array([[4,6,1,4,1,6,8,4,3,1,9,8,6,7,7,5]])`

I want to do some predictions with it, using LSTM in Keras.

**Predicting value at t**

What are the batch_sizes, timesteps, epochs etc if I want to use past values to predict the one at `t`?

Suppose I want to use `t-2` and `t-1` to predict `t`. Then I can create this train datasets:

```
xtrain = np.array([[4,6
                    6,1
                    1,4
                    4,1
                    1,6
                    6,8
                    8,4
                    4,3
                    3,1
                    1,9
                    9,8
                    8,6
                    6,7
                    7,7]])

ytrain = np.array([[1,
                    4,
                    1,
                    6,
                    8,
                    4,
                    3,
                    1,
                    9,
                    8,
                    6,
                    7,
                    7,
                    5]])
```

Each column/feature in `xtrain` has one lag from the column of `ytrain`. This mean that the first column of `xtrain` will contain the values at `t-2`, while the second column of `xtrain` will contain values at `t-1`.

This is how I would set up the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(number_units, input_shape = (samples, timesteps, features))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss= 'mse', optimizer = 'adam')
```

From my understanding **samples** would be equal to `len(xtrain)` = 14. **features** = `xtrain.shape[1]` = 2. But what would be timesteps?

The lag between the `ytrain` and the second column of `xtrain` is 1, and the lag between the second column of `xtrain` and the first column of `xtrain` is one again. So I am tempted to say that `timesteps` is 1? But surely it means something else. So what does it mean?

Also, if I put 1, I would have

```
   model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(number_units, input_shape = (14, 1, 2))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss= 'mse', optimizer = 'adam')
```

and to fit the model, I would have 
`model.fit(xtrain.reshape(xtrain.shape[0], 1, xtrain.shape[1]), epochs = e, batch_size = bs))`
What would be batch size in this case and what epochs? Normally an epochs is when the NN has gone through the whole `xtrain`, while a `batch_size` is the number of training examples after which the model updates the weights. But does it even make sense in an LSTM?

So if I set `batch_size` equal to `3` for instance, what would the model actually do?

My understanding is:

it will take 
`[[4,6
  6,1
  1,4]]`
feed this into the LSTM, and update the weights.
Then It would take 
`[[4,1
  1,6
  6,8]]`
and update the weights, etc. After it arrives to  `[[6,7], [7,7]]`, it will count this as an epoch.  Is this correct?

And what would change if I had put timesteps = 2?

What would have happened if I wanted to predict `t`, t+1`, etc? Would this influence the timesteps?

Answer (score 6):

I also had this question before. On a higher level, in `(samples, time steps, features)`

1. `samples` are the number of data, or say how many rows are there in your data set
2. `time step` is the number of times to feed in the model or `LSTM`
3. `features` is the number of columns of each sample

For me, I think a better example to understand it is that in `NLP`, suppose you have a sentence to process, then here sample is 1, which means 1 sentence to read, `time step` is the number of words in that sentence, you feed in the sentence word by word before the model read all the words and get a whole context of that sentence, `features` here is the dimension of each word, because in word embedding like `word2vec` or `glove`, each word is interpreted by a vector with multiple dimensions.

The `input_shape` parameter in `Keras` is only `(time_steps, num_features)`,
more you can refer to [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/). 
That's basically how I understand this, hope make it clear for you.